# A regular expression for \b

Tags: regex, unicode, word-boundary, word-boundaries

I am writing regular expressions for unicode text in Java. However for the particular script that I am using - Devanagari (0900 - 097F) there is a problem with word boundaries. \b matches characters which are dependent vowels(like 093E-094C) as they are treated like space characters.

Example:
Suppose I have the string: "कमल कमाल कम्हल कम्हाल"
Note that 'मा' in the 2nd word is formed by combining म and ा (recognized as a space character). Similarly in the last word.
This leads \b to match the 'ल' in 'कमाल' with regular expression \b\w\b which is not correct according to the language.

I hope the example helps.

Can I write a regular expression that behaves like \b except that it doesn't match certain chars? Any feedback will be grateful.

Comment: Added an example. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Could it be done with the [^ ] (not in range) expression?

Comment: You should make Laurence's answer the official one: he was the first to answer ;)

Comment: Done. Thanks for the help everyone :)
Stackoverflow rocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want with the following regex operators:

```
(?=X)   X, via zero-width positive lookahead
(?!X)   X, via zero-width negative lookahead
(?<=X)  X, via zero-width positive lookbehind
(?<!X)  X, via zero-width negative lookbehind
```

(The above is quoted from the [Java 6 Pattern API docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).)

Use `(?<![foo])(?=[foo])` in place of `\b` before a word, and  `(?<=[foo])(?![foo])` in place of `\b` after a word, where "`[foo]`" is your set of "word characters"

Comment: I thought about doing that but after reading http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html I was a bit confused if it would work.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent for word boundaries (if the boundaries are not what you were expecting for) would be:

```
 (?<!=[x-y])(<?=[x-y])...(?<=[x-y])(?![x-y])
```

That is because a "word boundary" means "a location where there is a character on one side and not on the other)

So with look-behind and look-ahead expressions, you can define you own class of characters [x-y] to check when you want to isolate a "word boundary"

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. Both yours and Laurence's answer is right which do I mark as correct? :D